# Mongoose save fail without error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, robo3t

I got success message, without document creation.

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

var conn = mongoose.createConnection(mongodb://localhost:27017/social_media);
var testModel = conn.model('test', new mongoose.Schema({
    key: { type: String, required: true }
}));
var test = new testModel();
test.key = 'hello';
test.save().then(function(tmp) {
    console.log('success');
    console.log(tmp);
}).catch( function() {
    console.log('failure');
});
```

As a result I get in console 'success' message with created object - so as I assume, document should be successfully inserted. In the moment of code run, database and collection don't exist. After code run, only db is created.

I tried to change 'createConnection' to 'connect' without any result.

I have already checked plenty of similar answers, but still can't find solution.

I'm using `MongoDB v3.2.8`, `node.js MongoDbDriver v2.2.5` and `Mongoose v4.5.8`

Comment: What's the command you're using to check to see if the document was created?

Comment: I'm using Robomongo GUI. I hadn't got any problem with that program before, so generally I think that it shows a good state of db.

Comment: @JohnnyHK, damn, you gave me the right path. That's GUI problem. While I'm listing documents by shell, I got them. You can add answer and then I will accept it.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Go ahead and provide your own answer and then accept that. Or just delete the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fault was in used GUI. I was using RoboMongo v0.8.5 and MongoDb v.3.2.8. The problem is that RoboMongo in that version is not supporting used MongoDb version. The full suport for mongo 3.x, came with RoboMongo v.0.9.0 - http://blog.robomongo.org/robomongo-rc1-with-full-support-for-mongodb-3/